# I have the full name, need to get the first and last initials only

Tags: t-sql

I have a fieled with the first and last name separated by a space, ex. John Cena
I want to get the first and last initials ex. JC
Please tell me how I can acheive that.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1):

How I'd do it.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'Alan Burstein';

SELECT Initials = LEFT(SUBSTRING(@name,1,f.M-1),1)+LEFT(SUBSTRING(@name,f.M+1,8000),1)
FROM (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',@name))) AS f(M);
```

**Returns:** AB

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'John Cena';

select left(@name,1) + substring(@name,CHARINDEX(' ',@name)+1,1) as name
```